# How to link css files to work correctly with wamp server?

Tags: php, css, dreamweaver

I have this line in the head of a php.page

```
<link href="css/header.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

LiveView in dw - shows everything formated well (css works)
f12 (using wamp) - also works well.
Now, I changed some line in header.css (for example cell padding) - then File - Save All
Live View still works - shows the changes correctly
But f12 (wamp) does not show the changes.
If I move header.css file from css folder to the root folder (and change the link) - wamp works well
But I want to have my css files in css folder, not in the root folder.
What is the solution, please?

Comment: you can set baseurl in html and set it to your root directory (absolute)

Comment: Change your path to css from webroot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear your browser cache. That should fix the issue.
You can do it automatically if you use ctrl+F5 in your browser.

Comment: gilles, clearing the browser cache - WORKS. ThankYou. Maybe, how could I clear the cache automatically, before running the wamp?

Comment: @Alice when refreshing you page use `ctrl + F5` - this will refresh your cash at the same time

Comment: Hey Lix, sorry for that, i wanted to post a comment but i couldn't. Be sure i'll do that next time.

Answer (score 2):

Find your web root path and append it to the css file

Example.

```
<link href="<?php echo $webroot?>/yourfolder/css/header.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
<link href="css/header.css<?php echo '?rnd_'.urlencode(time()).'='.urlencode(rand()); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

For debugging purposes this is ideal, because it appends a random query string to the CSS-file-request in order not to be cached.